# Display specific product child category title on Woocommerce product based on parent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce shop that has its products organized by parent categories such as Brand, Color, Size, etc.  Each of these top-level categories has a number of subcategories: for example, subcategories of Color include Red, Blue, Pink, etc.

Client wants to display each product's brand and size (the products are shoes) below each product thumbnail in the grid/loop view on the front and archive pages.

Each product is only one brand, but might have multiple sizes available.

So essentially, I need to know if there's a way to display the title of only a specific subcategory for a single product, like so:

```
[Product Thumbnail here]
[Price info here]
Brand: Nike
Size(s): 8, 8.5, 9
```

I just need the subcat titles, not links.  I know the solution to this will likely involve calling the get_terms() function in content-product.php, but I haven't been able to figure out how to list only specific subcategories for a product.

The code I'm looking for will basically say:

```
If this product is in the Brand category,
    Then show its subcategory.

If this product is in the Size category,
    Then show its subcategories.
```

Comment: something like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ea6341ab9

Answer (score 0):

check this link :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

and paste this code in your shop page

```
global $product; 

// Get product attributes
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {
    echo "No attributes";
}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        echo $attribute['name'] . ": ";
        $product_attributes = array();
        $product_attributes = explode('|',$attribute['value']);

        $attributes_dropdown = '<select>';

        foreach ( $product_attributes as $pa ) {
            $attributes_dropdown .= '<option value="' . $pa . '">' . $pa . '</option>';
        }

        $attributes_dropdown .= '</select>';

        echo $attributes_dropdown;
}
```

Comment: Very similar to this, but not even this complex.  I don't even need the dropdowns: I just need the code to spit out the brand and size categories that the product is in for use as a description.